# document.ready and javascript file not loading after in Ajax success

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am loading partial view in modal popup in ajax success block. but javascript files related to new partial view are not loading. also `document.ready function` in new partial view is not getting called.

here I have employee form (in modal popup). after employee submit, I have to refresh same modal popup with employee contact form. after submit employee contact form is getting opened in same modal popup but it breaks because external javascript file related to that new view are not getting loaded.

below is code -

```
 $("body #EmployeeModal").on("submit", "#EmployeeNewForm", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();  
            //alert('working');
            var form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: form.attr("action"),
                method: form.attr("method"),  // post
                data: form.serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    
                    $("body #EmployeeModal .modal-body").load('Employee/EmployeeContact?empid=' + result, function () {

                        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
```

I also tried returning direct partial view result and used `$(this).html(result)` instead `$("#").load()` but it serves only static html and no javascript eventhandler is working.

is it possible that in ajax success, there is timing and sync issue of new partial view with javascript file.

Comment: Can you show the action pls?

Comment: @Serge the return statement in action is `return PartialView("EmployeeContact", employee);`